# What is baking?

Tags: mesh, texturing, baking

What is baking used for? How does it help me?

It's a simple question and I don't understand why this site gives me such a hard time trying to ask anything.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, and we have rules to follow. When we downvote/upvote things, it's never personal. Hovering over those buttons says why we would do it. We're always only trying to help you, and others.

Comment: This is a broad question, it's not even related directly to Blender, since backing is a generic operation in most 3D software, answering this question in details, will take pages, or a tutorial, which is not what this site is for. A simple answer as the one Carlo provided a link to is already available, but you can find lots of detailed answers on other tutorials sites, or Youtube.

Comment: @Georges I think this is a great question for folks using blender and other 3D apps.

Comment: @cegaton, I agree, and the short answer is already provided in BSE, don't you think?

Comment: Its like painting shadows/colors onto the object, instead of recalculating the shadows constantly. If you bake the shadows, they wont change even if you rotate the light, etc.  This way you can export your models into other software with textures on them or you simply save yourself the hours of contently  re-rendering good quality textures.